# php how to get values from a var problem?

Tags: php

I have a small PHP script that takes the values from a dropdown list and attaches some other strings to them:

```
$options = array(
    '1' => 'Backgammon',
    '2' => 'Chess',
);
$value = $_POST['gamelist'];
echo $options[$value];
```

What if I want to grab the values from a variable instead of a dropdown list? How do I do that? My var is:

```
$defences_results = $game_set->get_my_defences();
foreach( $defences_results as $key => $value) {
    print '<li>'.$value['stake'].' </li>
}
```

The print displays `1`, `2`, etc. I want to replace that with: `Backgammon`, `Chess`, etc.
What I was doing is using `.$options[$value].`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so do:

```
$defences_results = $game_set->get_my_defences();
foreach( $defences_results as $key => $value){
   print '<li>'.$options[$value['stake']].' </li>';
}
```